# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые, рискну ещё раз отвлечь ваше внимание и попросить помощи в исправлении некритической консольной ошибки

Здесь http://jsfiddle.net/BFha6/ при клике на `#labelContainer` в консоле появляется следующее сообщение об ошибке

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Не получается от него избавиться. Пробовал проверять существование переменной `article` в контроллере, но не помогает(

Comment: Сама переменная `article` пустая. Смотрите, почему ничего не передается в функцию `onArticleMouseClick()`

Comment: в том то и дело, что проверял. я делал проверку даже в самой функции  onArticleMouseClick(), примерно так
 function onArticleMouseClick(article){
  var visibleElement = article.getElementsByTagName('span')[0], 
   hiddenElement = article.getElementsByTagName('span')[1];
        
        if(article){
  
            textToggle(visibleElement, hiddenElement);}
  
  return;
 }

Comment: Потому что судя по всему поиск должен идти внутрь блока с articles, а он идет наружу, поэтому тэг ARTICLE он никогда не находит. Нужно изменить рекурсивный поиск в функции lookUpElement в нужную сторону

Comment: .

    var visibleElement = article.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
    // console.log(article); // null
    // null.getElementsByTagName(...) == Cannot call method of null

Comment: это помогло разобраться. спасибо

Comment: нет проблем, учитесь пользоватся инструментами разработчика вашего браузера и вы сами, без труда, в течении, буквально, нескольких секунд, сможете находить причины такого рода ошибок.